# Does Outlook (for Android) always move new senders to Focused Inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

... because all Spam received is, unsurprisingly, from unknown, new senders. In other words: will it learn that my received mails are Non-Focus by default? Or is moving spam to the "Other" tab a waste of time?

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? It's about Outlook, and how a specific feature of it works?

Comment: I agree that this is about an Outlook feature. Not sure why people voted it off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new folder called "Clutter" which when activated should "learn" that the stuff from unknown senders is not being read by you and should be eventually dumped there automatically. Here is the article on how it works: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Clutter-to-sort-low-priority-messages-in-Outlook-7b50c5db-7704-4e55-8a1b-dfc7bf1eafa0

Normally if you don't read these emails and delete them or move them to spam, it should trigger the move.

Comment: I'm waiting patiently for the Algo to learn that I don't focus on spam. From what I read, the only major difference between clutter and focused inbox is replacing the folder (which doesn't exist in my account) with a tab style representation. I hope deleting really trains the Algo.

Comment: Normally it should work, epecially if they are still marked as unread.

Comment: Seems to gradually place more incoming messages from unknown senders into the "Other" tab now. Thanks for the hint that not reading / deleting counts as well, saved me lots of time.